# Issue while starting application on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat

Facing below issue while starting an application. Can anyone guide?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'library' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Properties' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Comment: The evaluation of one of your [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) expressions `#{...}` failed. Can your provide more details on how you configure your beans? XML, `@Value` annotations? Anyway the full stack trace would help pinpointing the invalid expression.

Comment: It is resolved now. Actually I was trying to read a property named "library" in application-context.xml . But it was not mentioned in VM argument. That is why the issue was coming.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved now. Actually I was trying to read a property named "library" in application-context.xml . But it was not mentioned in VM argument. That is why the issue was coming.

Mentioned the -Dlibrary="" in VM arguments. this solved the problem.